# How can I make a custom Notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I have been struggling in these last two days to find a way to make a custom android notification. I have passed by the remote views solution but this solution is very limited to changing the layout only. What I need is to put a custom view(other than text views, image views, and these typical views that are usually seen in a notification) in a notification. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but this solution is very limited to changing the layout only

I do not know what you mean by this. The `RemoteViews` can certainly have more than a layout manager (e.g., `LinearLayout`); otherwise, it would pointless.

> What I need is to put a custom view(other than text views, image views, and these typical views that are usually seen in a notification) in a notification. Is that possible?

You are welcome to try whatever `RemoteViews` supports, minus the `AdapterView` subclasses (e.g., `ListView`). Interactive widgets, such as buttons, will be unreliable, particularly on Android 1.x/2.x, as vendor customizations to the notification tray sometimes prevent interactive widgets from working properly.

Comment: Can I put a widget host?

Comment: @TurkiAlKhatib: No. You did not write the system UI that implements the notification tray, and it is that UI that would have to be the app widget host. Remember: the `Notification` is *not* being rendered by your app in your process. You are *describing* a UI, in the form of a `Notification` and optional `RemoteViews`, that is being rendered by another hunk of code in another process. That IPC mechanism is intentionally limited in scope, and so you cannot do arbitrary things.

Comment: But I already saw apps that implemented that and successfully put widgets and even apps in the notification tray, like custom notifications app in the play store. So I concluded that there should be a way to achieve this.

Comment: @TurkiAlKhatib: "successfully put widgets and even apps in the notification tray" -- name any.

Comment: Custom notification :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.shekeen.WidgetHolder

Comment: Notification toggle :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle

Comment: @TurkiAlKhatib: The first one is presumably displaying an `ImageView`, where they have an `AppWidgetHost` running in the background that pretends to be a home screen. Per your prior comment regarding a widget host, you can't put the widget host *in* the `Notification`, but you could take information *from* a widget host, like the rendered app widget on a `Canvas`, and use that in a `RemoteViews`. The second is presumably using `ImageView` widgets as well, and they change the image in the `ImageView` upon a click.

Comment: @TurkiAlKhatib: In other words, neither of those examples, based solely on the Play Store screenshots and general functional descriptions, would appear to be beyond the boundaries of what you can do with `RemoteViews`.

Answer (score 0):

A simplest example of custom notification

```html
private void showCustomeNoti() {

  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
    this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  RemoteViews mContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
    R.layout.custome_notification_layout);
  mBuilder.setContent(mContentView);
  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  mNotificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());

 }
```

Call this function when you want to show custom notification.

Comment: I described in the question that this way does not work for me. Thanks